# Converting numeric matrix column to datetime column

Tags: matlab

I have a `1000x5 double` matrix:

```
79  735727,416666667    735727,452083333    735727,479166667    2
80  735727,441666667    735727,483333333    735727,506250000    9
81  735727,506944445    735727,534722222    735727,561111111    2
82  735727,541666667    735727,604861111    735727,648611111    9
83  735727,556944444    735727,572916667    735727,602083333    7
```

2rd, 3rd, 4th columns are dates. I want to replace their numerical representation with their datetime representation. I convert these columns like this:

```
arrive_date = datestr(data(:, 2))
arrive_date = datetime(arrive_date)
```

**But, can't assign it back to the `data's` column**:

```
data(:, 2) = arrive_date
```

**Error:** The following error occurred converting from datetime to double:
Undefined function 'double' for input arguments of type 'datetime'. To convert from datetimes to numeric, first subtract off a datetime origin, then convert to numeric using the SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, DAYS, or YEARS functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't store date objects in an array of doubles. You will need to use a cell array if you want to mix types. See the example below:

```
data = [79  735727.416666667    735727.452083333    735727.479166667    2;
        80  735727.441666667    735727.483333333    735727.506250000    9];
arrive_date = datestr(data(:, 2))
arrive_date = datetime(arrive_date)

% Convert to cell array (each column is contained in a cell)
data = num2cell(data,1);

data{2} = arrive_date
```

The output shows the new type (second cell is a vector of `datetime` objects).

```
data =

  1×5 cell array

    [2×1 double]    [2×1 datetime]    [2×1 double]    [2×1 double]    [2×1 double]
```